# How did the Joker plant bombs in the hospital?

Tags: the-dark-knight

In [The Dark Knight (2008)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0468569), the Joker calls into a TV show where Reese is about to reveal Batman's identity, and says that if Reese isn't dead within 60 (90?) minutes, then he [the Joker] would blow up a hospital.

I'm not even going to ask how the Joker knew Reese was on TV, but how did he get the bombs planted in the hospital so quickly and without being noticed? Were the bombs pre-planted? If so, then why? He had no idea Reese was going to go on TV. Did the Joker know that a police officer had a family member in the hospital? If so, that might make sense as he could have planned to use the "I'm going to blow up a hospital" bit for some other reason.

Answer (score 6):

The Joker is shown to be psychotic, intelligent, and uncaring. He also is great at finding someone's weakness and exploiting them (the cop in the interrogating room). This is how he got the female officer to trap Dent and take him to the warehouse. At the beginning of the film she says she just checked her mom back into the hospital. Given that piece of information, we can assume he did something similar to other people to get access to the hospital and plant bombs. He probably bribed and threaten a few people who had access to the hospital (nurses, security, someone from the cleaning crew, etc...)

The Joker doesn't leave much to chance, and plans everything in detail, however, with Batman and the police right behind him he has to improvise on the spot once in a while.

He always planned to blow up the hospital, he just saved it for when he needed it.

Comment: It is kind of convenient he knew that Harvey would be in that hospital (and/or Rachel if she survived his bombs) but my guess is he planted the bomb in the biggest hospital in the city which was where Harvey was sent.